# How to encode a series of optional tokens in YACC (/RACC)

Tags: ruby, parsing, token, option-type, yacc

I'm trying to write a RACC parser, a part of which can be represented by the regular expression `a[b][c][d]`.

I came up with the following productions (each token represents the lower case character of the token name):

```
  expr
    : A
    | A b
    ;

  b
    : B
    | B c
    | c
    ;

  c
    : C
    | C D
    | D
```

Is this the simplest form, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B`. `C`, and `D` can be distinguished from each other by their first token (which is certainly the case if they are tokens rather than being the simplification of a more complicated grammar), then an alternative is to define non-terminals representing optionality.

```
optional_B: /* empty */ | B
optional_C: /* empty */ | C
optional_D: /* empty */ | D 
expression: A optional_B optional_C optional_D
```

This gets more complicated when the optional subexpressions cannot be immediately distinguished, because the parser needs to correctly identify that the optional non-terminal matches the empty string based only on the following token. But it sounds like that's not the case with your grammar.